# Ruby resources for messenger bot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bots, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

We are creating a messenger bot with rails and are looking for some gens

We found [Lita](https://rubygems.org/gems/lita) which looks nice but I wanted to know if there was any other cool ruby resources we might use for the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few.

Botstack is built on Rails with some pretty nice features like supporting webviews and help with web scraping.
https://github.com/davidmann4/botstack

I've built a messenger client that is pretty alpha but it is also fairly complete and I feel, nice to use.
https://github.com/pferdefleisch/messenger_client

Here is another pretty complete library that provides you with some request handlers as well as a messenger client. I believe it is used in botstack.
https://github.com/hyperoslo/facebook-messenger

This should get you started. I'm working on my own framework and will update the answer if I ever get it released.